# What are SO incentives for editing a post?

Tags: discussion, edits, reputation, gamification

What are the current incentives for editing a post on Stack Overflow? Do you receive reputation for edits or something? I see some people editing hundreds of posts every day and I just can't imagine that they are doing it for fun haha!

Comment: Sorry if this question is improper for this site. I thought Meta was for asking Q&A about S/O. If I'm wrong let me know about why this was down-voted so that I can learn please! Thanks

Comment: Your question is fine, and in the right place. I cannot speak for others as to the downvotes, but I would *guess* they are because this info is fairly easy to find in the help section and other questions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do get reputation for approved [suggested edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work); if you have less than 2000 reputation (and thus lack the [editing privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)), you get 2 points, with a lifetime maximum of 1000, for each suggestion you make that's approved.

Beyond that, there are some [badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges) that you can earn for doing a certain number of edits.

For myself, the main reason I edit -- and I think I do a fair bit of editing -- is that it's such a good way to contribute to Stack Overflow as a knowledge archive. Making a question clearer means that it's more likely to get a good answer, and to be found once it has that answer. Making an answer better means that I've assisted in that information's dissemination. I don't do it for reputation; I do it because I feel good about making posts easier to read, find, and understand. For me, it's just as important as answering.

Comment: Very detailed answer with links! Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 7):

> What are the current incentives of editing a post on Stack overflow?

1. You get to be a part of making questions and answers useful,
   readable, and so valuable, which may well help a lot of other
   people.
2. You get a sense of satisfaction that you are contributing and giving
   back from the questions and help you have had.
3. Oh, yeah, and I suppose it's worth also mentioning you get 2 rep
   everytime your edit is approved, when your total rep is < 2000.

But don't make pointless edits to gain rep, make them worthwhile because other users have to review your edit suggestion, and pointless edits will be rejected. Too many rejections and you can lose the privilege of edits.

> I see some people editing hundreds of posts every day and I just can't imagine that they are doing it for fun haha!

See 1. and 2. above ;)

Answer (score 4):

Anyone with less than 2k rep at the time of editing will receive +2 rep upon acceptance.

And, of course, many just dislike seeing questions with glaring flaws of various sorts, or that could be much more answerable with a few tweaks.

Comment: Gotcha! And users with over 2k rep receive not bonus reputation for an edit?

Comment: Nope. After all, no one is checking their edits.

Comment: "users with over 2k rep receive not bonus reputation for an edit" No. If they did, overnight the site would be awash with a billion terrible edits and sudden influx of users with mega rep/20k mod tools they shouldn't have - given how they'd earned them...